# When i run the Route given Below a 500 interal server error arises on postman , this Route was working fine until it is not

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, routes

```
  router.get("/",function(req,res){
    const empp =  employee.find().sort("lastName")
         res.json(empp); 
  });
```

`when i run this route on postman , earlier it was working fine showing me the response by suddenly a
Converting circular structure to JSON
error arises

i even rolled backed to the point where the code was working fine by control+z but this /employees route is giving this error`

Comment: what is `employee.find()` ? is it an async function?